# Idiomatic usage of React Context API with TypeScript's strict initialization

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm trying to convert already-functioning React application, so it will adhere to TypeScript strict rules, and got a bit stuck with context API. The ordinary way to use it is as following:

```
// context type and producer are defined in one place for the whole project
import GlobalContext from '../context/GlobalContext';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    public context: React.ContextType<typeof GlobalContext>;
    // other component logic
}
MyComponent.contextType = GlobalContext;
```

But, with strict class initialization TypeScript shows an error, telling that the `context` property is not initialized in the constructor - and it really isn't, since it will be initialized by React.

For now, I can use the definite assignment assertion to "fix" this:

```
public context!: React.ContextType<typeof GlobalContext>;
```

But is there some more idiomatic solution?

Comment: one more reason why hooks are great..